# CSS3 @support directive throwing error during SASS compile

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, node-sass

I am trying to compile this SASS:

```
@supports (display: flex) {
  .event_entry  {
    @include flexbox;
    @include flexwrap;
  }
}
```

I am using node-sass 0.9.3 (i.e. libsass) via grunt-sass 0.13.1. However, I am getting this error:

```
error: error reading values after display
```

The line number associated with the error is the very first line, the line containing the @supports directive.

I believe that this is valid SASS/CSS and I have successfully compiled this same declaration using grunt-contrib-sass 0.7.3. This implies that it is an issue with libsass not supporting the syntax, but AFAIK the @support directive has been around for a long time now, so that seems unlikely. I would very much like to use node-sass if possible since it promises much faster compile speeds. What can I do to get this working?

Comment: libsass != sass.  The only people who can help you with this are the maintainers of libsass, I suggest you take this up with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, this is a bug in libsass.

https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/261

Comment: Just as a heads up, the bug is now resolved. Make sure you have the latest node-sass/lib-sass/grunt-sass/gulp-sass :).

Comment: It's not fixed at all. I have the latest version here and it still breaks.